# Jquery Multiple events for form submit not waiting

Tags: jquery

I have to check unique email ids in my project. for that i am using json and returning the value. it works fine. the code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Add the page method call as an onblur handler for the email textbox.
        $("#<%= txtPrimEmail.ClientID %>").blur(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "customerEmail.asmx/CheckCustEmail",
                data: "{mailId: '" + $("#<%= txtPrimEmail.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (msg.d != "0") {
                        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                        document.getElementById('pm').value = "1";
                        $("#duplicate").text('This email has already been taken');
                        var myInputOffset = $('#<%= txtPrimEmail.ClientID %>').offset(); // Get the position of the input field relative to the document
                        $('#duplicate').css({ 'top': myInputOffset.top + 25, 'left': myInputOffset.left + 100, 'visibility': 'visible' }); // Position the div
                        $("#<%= txtPrimEmail.ClientID %>").removeClass().addClass("ErrorTxt");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#<%= txtPrimEmail.ClientID %>").removeClass().addClass("textbox");
                        $("#duplicate").text('');
                        $('#duplicate').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I am doing the same for secondary email text box also.

the pbm is, If i type on the textbox and click outside the textbox, and then hit the submit button,... the function is working fine.  But It is not working  if i type on the textbox and without clicking outside the textbox , i hit submit button - the function not firing. So i have called the same function in form submit also:

```
 $('form').submit(function() {
            $("#<%= txtPrimEmail.ClientID %>").trigger('blur');
        });

        $('form').submit(function() {
            $("#<%= txtSecEmail.ClientID %>").trigger('blur');
        });

        $('form').submit(function() {
            var pOk = document.getElementById('pm').value;
            var sOk = document.getElementById('sm').value;
           //here i am checking email errors and returning false;
            //return false;

        });
```

the problem now is, before the error div displays, it calls the last submit event...i have tried using callback also.. not seems to work...

Sorry for posting such a long question...
Anyone please help.....

Comment: Not for sure if you are required to use just jquery, but the jquery validate plugin has the functionality you are looking for built in.  Look at jQuery validate and specifically the 'remote' attribute.

Comment: thanks . though i need a solution for this.. why the textbox blur is not firing if not clicked out side?